# Conditional join on different columns

Tags: sql, pyspark

What is the most effective way to write this in pyspark:

Pseudocode:

```
table1 inner join table2 
on cookies if table1.cookie is not Null 
else join on ids
```

table1:

```
id, cookie
1, 1q2w
2, Null
```

table2:

```
id, cookie
1, 1q2w
2, 3e4r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On pyspark side, you can create two df based on whether table1.cookie is null or not then merge them

```
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> df1 = table1.where(F.isnull('cookie')==True).join(table2, table1.id == table2.id, 'inner').select(table1.id,table2.cookie)
>>> df2 = table1.where(F.isnull('cookie')==False).join(table2, table1.cookie == table2.cookie, 'inner').select(table1.id,table2.cookie)
>>> df1.union(df2).show()
+---+------+                                                                    
| id|cookie|
+---+------+
|  2|  3e4r|
|  1|  1q2w|
+---+------+
```

Comment: Union of joins is most readable and works for me nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OR` as in the answers so far submitted. In my experience, though, joins with `or` perform very badly. You can also use a `UNION|UNION ALL`:

```
select * 
from table1 
inner join table2 
on table1.cookies= table2.cookies

UNION (ALL) -- UNION removes duplicates, UNION ALL keeps them.

select * 
from table1 
inner join table2 
on table1.id=table2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using OR

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c5925f7c71ce3c2eb01278c776bf462c)

```
select * from 
table1 inner join table2 
on table1.cookies= table2.cookies or table1.id=table2.id
```

Comment: How does it work? Where is "if null condition"? Won't there appear duplicates?

Comment: @bry888, you can check here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c5925f7c71ce3c2eb01278c776bf462c - It will not produce duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Join on cookies **or** on IDs when table1.cookie is null:

```
select *
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.cookie = t2.cookie
               or (t1.cookie is null and t1.id = t2.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way is often to use `left join`s:

```
select . . .,
       coalesce(t2c.colx, t2i.colx) as colx
from table1 t1 inner join
     table2 t2c
     on t1.cookie = t2.cookie left join
     table2 t2i
     on t1.id = t2i.id and t2c.cookie is null
```